# SQLAlchemy and (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

So,a after reading every page around for the last 1h i'm still not able to find a solution for this problem.

This is my **connection.py** file:

```
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, Integer, MetaData
  from sqlalchemy.sql import select


  class DatabaseConnectionManager:

      def __init__(self):
          self.host = 'localhost:3306'
          self.db = 'xxx'
          self.user = 'xxx'
          self.pwd = 'xxx'
          self.connect_string = 'mysql://{u}:{p}@{s}/{d}'.format(u=self.user,
                                                                 p=self.pwd,
                                                                 s=self.host,
                                                                 d=self.db)
          self.metadata = MetaData()
          self.engine = create_engine(self.connect_string, echo=False,
                                      pool_size=100, pool_recycle=3600)

          self.conn = self.engine.connect()


      def insert_table(self, inputs):
          self.conn.execute(self.tbl_auctions().insert(), inputs)
          # Update 1 : conn.close() removed.
          #self.conn.close()

      def select_servers(self):
          try:
              s = select([self.tbl_servers()])
              result = self.conn.execute(s)
          except:
              raise
          else:
              return result
```

And this is my **bulk_inserter.py** file:

```
import sys
import time
import json
from connector import DatabaseConnectionManager

def build_auctions_list():

    server_list = []
    db = DatabaseConnectionManager()
    # Loop over regions
    for server, env in db.select_servers_table():

        request_auction_data = json.loads(dump_auction_url(region, realm))

        for auction in request_auction_data:
            auction_list.append(auction)
        db.insert_table(server_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    build_auctions_list()
    print time.time() - start
```

So, the problem happens when i try to insert all the bulk data using **db.insert_table(server_list)** for 2 or more servers returned by the loop **for server, env in db.select_servers_table():**

But, if the result on that loop is for only one server, the flows happen normally without problems.

So, resuming :

1. this program retrieve a list of servers from a db table and dumps the json data into the db.
2. Bulk insert performs well if only one server is retrieved.
3. if two or more servers , the following error happens:

   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Anyoen have any idea what could be happening? I allready incresed the timeout and buffer size on mysql config file. So i'm not sure what the problem could be...

**Update #1** It seems i cant bulk insert array with more than 50k values. I'm still trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Well yeah, you're closing the connection in `insert_table`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser allready removed, but still not working...